# Rollback transaction error in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a shopping cart system in my rails app by following this [tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails). Everything worked fine but when i try to add a product(in my case it's chair) all i get is a pop up saying Not Valid, the terminal shows no errors other then **Rollback Trasaction**.

**My Product Model**

```
class Chair < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :previewo, PreviewoUploader
    mount_uploader :previewt, PreviewtUploader
    mount_uploader :previewth, PreviewthUploader
    has_many :order_items
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 600 }
    default_scope { where(active: true) }
end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_status
    belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

**order_item.rb**

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chair
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :chair_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      chair.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def chair_present
    if chair.nil?
      errors.add(:chair, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

**OrderStatus.rb**

```
class OrderStatus < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
end
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Started POST "/order_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-05 22:42:29 +0530
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "chair_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Add to Cart"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Chair Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "chairs".* FROM "chairs" WHERE "chairs"."active" = ? AND "chairs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["active", "t"], ["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering order_items/create.js.erb
  Rendered order_items/create.js.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Comment: What popup are you seeing?  What is the rollback error?

Comment: Btw, you can write `order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum` as `order_items.sum { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }`

Comment: @ruby_newbie as i have mentioned the pop just say Not Valid, and there is no error coming with the rollback, it's just saying Transaction rollback, sorry for less information, i am new to rails.

Comment: @ruby_newbie i have added the whole terminal output

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the chair in the order_items params does not exist.  If you go to the rails console and enter `Chair.find(3)`.  I expect the chair doesn't exist.  Your chair_present validation in order_items is stopping the transaction from going through because the chair doesn't exist yet.  You need to create the chair before you associate anything to it.

change your order_items_controller to this to verify:

```
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    if @order.save
        session[:order_id] = @order.id
      else
        puts "Order Item failed to save because #{@order.errrors}"
    end
  end
```

then you should see an output to the console telling you why it failed to save.